# Can't access a secret stored in secrets manager for a service account having google_secret_manager_secret_iam_binding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam, gcp-secrets-manager

I'm trying to give a given GCE instance the permission to get one specific secret stored inside the secret manager. Not the WHOLE set of secrets, just one.

So, I added this binding in my terraform code for the service account which in turn is used inside my GCE:

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret_iam_binding" "secret_iam_binding" {
  project   = <my project>
  # I also used google_secret_manager_secret.<my secret>.secret_id here, but nothing changed     
  secret_id = google_secret_manager_secret.<my secret>.name
  role      = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
  members   = [
    "serviceAccount:${<the service account used by the GCE instance>.email}"
  ]
}
```

This is the relevant code into the GCE creation terraform block: the scope should be enough I guess...

```
service_account {
    email = <the service account used by the GCE instance>.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
```

Then, i ssh into the GCE node and tried to make some checks (since i have Container OS there, i had to use curl for testing)

- Check if GCE is using the right service account: OK

```
curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

- Getting a valid token: OK (well, I assume so)

```
TOKEN=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | jq -r .access_token)
```

- Getting the secret value: KO

```
curl -s "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<my project id>/secrets/<my secret name>/versions/latest" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq -r .payload.data | base64 -d
```

with this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'secretmanager.versions.get' denied for resource 'projects/<my project id>/secrets/<my secret name>/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

thus, I guess I'm not granting enough roles to the service account....but I've no clue on which one I'm missing...

EDIT: outside the GCE node, I tried this command:

```
gcloud secrets get-iam-policy <my secret id> --project <my project id>
```

and the output is the expected:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:<my service account name>>@<my project id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
etag: BwX8DrYyZtw=
version: 1
```

Comment: Check the VM's Access Scopes in the web console GUI. It must be set to cloud platform all APIs. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

Comment: @JohnHanley tnx, I did...all API's are granted

Comment: The error is `secretmanager.versions.get`. The IAM role `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor` does not have that permission [link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control).

Comment: Verify that `<my secret name>` is a valid Secret ID.

Comment: double checked that...but maybe i've an idea still to check  (i'm going to provide an answer if it will solve the issue). Tnx in the meantime for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went out that the endpoint I was using to get the payload was incomplete. In facts, the structure was totally wrong:

```
curl -s "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<my project id>/secrets/<my secret name>/versions/latest:access" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq -r .payload.data | base64 -d
```

In other words, I was missing the ":access" trail.